# Jquery + AJAX + PHP - document.write faild to execute 3rd party application

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

I searched a lot in the internet looking for a solution but nothing helped me, took me 3 days already sitting on this issue and have not come out with a solution.

I'm using WordPress. I integrated the `Echo Sign API` as a widget into my website, when I make a call with ajax to load `Echo Sign PHP file`, is starts to execute and it stops and displaying this into console:

> Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened. widget?f=9KIUFVC4Y524AZ&token=7O3WZTIYLYT5FR7GCGLSQ3QP&_=1406184564193:1

When I open this

```
widget?f=9KIUFVC4Y524AZ&token=7O3WZTIYLYT5FR7GCGLSQ3QP&_=1406184564193:1
```

Inside is this, (actually the `document.write` is causing the problem):

```
document.write('<iframe src="https://secure.echosign.com/public/embedesignhtml?rdid=9KIUFVC4Y524AZ&token=7O3WZTIYLYT5FR7GCGLSQ3QP&hosted=false&firstName=&lastName=&nameEditable=true&" width="772" height="690" frameborder="0" style="border: 0; overflow: hidden; min-height: 500px; min-width: 600px;"></iframe>');
```

I found some solution and they are working, but the problem is that when the PHP file is called, it generates automatically a script and that script is calling the iframe from above, the script contains unique data every time, because of this my static solution will not work.

Below I will put my code as well, maybe will help:

**Ajax Call:**

```
$('#my_id').html('').load('my_EchoSign.php', function(){

});
```

**my_EchoSign.php**

```
$file = EchoSign\Info\FileInfo::createFromFile($filepath);

$widget = new EchoSign\Info\WidgetCreationInfo('Test createPersonalEmbeddedWidget', $file);

$personalization = new EchoSign\Info\WidgetPersonalizationInfo($recipient_email);

try{
    $result_sign = $api->createPersonalEmbeddedWidget($widget, $personalization);
} catch(Exception $e) {
    print '<h3>An exception occurred:</h3>';
    var_dump($e);
}
echo $result_sign->{'embeddedWidgetCreationResult'}->javascript;
```

Actually the problem is starting when the php file is called and executed, then into `#my_id` is inserted a script that is calling the `document.write('<iframe>.....</iframe>')` and here it fails because of `document.write`.

Please I will appreciate any help.

Thanking you in advance.

Comment: Is the code calling document.write(..) your code, or part of a framework?

Comment: this one """""echo $result_sign->{'embeddedWidgetCreationResult'}->javascript;""""""" is calling document.write() .............. This result echo $result_sign->{'embeddedWidgetCreationResult'}->javascript; is inserting a script into my div and that script is calling the document.wrtie('here is an iframe').... @myninjaname

Comment: Can you rewrite the `document.write(..)` to `$(body).append(..)`?

Comment: What u mean, can u explain me? Actually i have no control on the script and the iframe that is called, i jsut generated parameters based on user inputs and creating the script that after is calling the documen.write...... The result of this echo $result_sign->{'embeddedWidgetCreationResult'}->javascript; is one script and next to it an iframe, for now is isnerting only the script and fails to insert the document.write (which contains the iframe...) @myninjaname

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you're stuck with code using `document.write`, load `my_EchoSign.php` in an `iframe`:

```
$('#my_id').html('<iframe src="my_EchoSign.php"></iframe>');
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it start to work like a charm. Can i ask you, why the document.write is not making problem while loading it into iframe? @myninjaname

Comment: @ionluchian Late response, but to answer your question: The code was loaded asynchronously and thus not able to write to the document, as the error message suggests (`"Failed to execute 'write' on 'Document': It isn't possible to write into a document from an asynchronously-loaded external script unless it is explicitly opened."`).  By loading it into an `iframe`, you are explicitly opening the content.